# Is it possible to select a element to hover it and it is not it's child with CSS only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have an `<aside>` and `<header>` and the header has child called container and cont. has some children one of them is called burger bar so what I want here is when I `:hover` the burger bar the `<aside>` will be visible so I wonder how to do that or if it is impossible I tried to do this `header .container .burger_bar:hover + aside` but the aside is not element beside the burger_bar so it's not going to work.

more explain...

```
<div class='header'> 
    <div class='container'>
         <div class='burger_bar'>...</div>
    </div>
</div>

<aside>...</aside> /* <---when hovering the burger bar this will be 
transform: translate(0%) right after being transform: translate(-100%) */
```

Comment: ```.burger_bar:hover aside```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to show a sibling of the ancestor of an element that is being hovered?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You'll need some Javascript for this as from your description aside is not a sibling or descendant of burger bar.

Answer (score 0):

If trigger and target are on the same level, you can use `.trigger:hover ~ .target` to target your `.target` element while `.trigger` is being hovered.

```css
.trigger:hover ~ .target {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="trigger">Hover Me</div>
<div class="target">Target</div>
```

If your trigger and target are not on the same level, it's better to use some javascript to add a class to your target.

```js
const trigger = document.querySelector('.trigger');
const target = document.querySelector('.target');

trigger.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  target.classList.add('active');
});

trigger.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  target.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```css
.target.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="trigger">Hover Me</div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
  <div class="target">Target</div>
</div>
```

Or you could use [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo class but be aware if its [poor coverage](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas) (only works in Safari right now)

```css
.parent1:has(.trigger:hover) ~ .parent2 .target {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="trigger">Hover Me</div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
  <div class="target">Target</div>
</div>
```